# Is Session in Meteor a misnomer?

Tags: meteor

Although I started using Meteor extensively only recently, the name "Session" for a `Session` object in Meteor feels like a misnomer to me. It is very different from how it's conventionally used across the web and I don't understand why it's named that way. Is there a specific reason to this or is it possible to rename it to something more suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Session` variable is a reactive data source which:

- can be globally accessed anywhere in your client code
- will survive a hot code push
- will not survive a hard reload

I agree that the name is confusing because of the last point. To answer your question, yes you *could* name it something else if you really wanted to. For example:

#### client/lib/session.js

```js
NotReallySession = Session;
```

Then elsewhere in your client code, you could do:

```js
NotReallySession.set('answer', 42);
NotReallySession.get('answer');
```

However, I'm not sure what you really gain by doing this.

A more attractive solution would be to use a package like [persistent-session](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session) which modifies the `Session` api to give you persistence across page refreshes by keeping values in localstorage.

Of particular interest may be the `Session.setAuth` function, which stores a persistent reactive value which is cleared on logout. In my view, this most closely aligns with the notion of "session" from other contexts.